# Export to csv queries API from azure devops Boards Queries

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops

I am currently working on automate a process where i manualy download a CSV from azure devops queries,then, i convert it into xlsx file and upload it manually to google drive
This is where i export to CSV.

[image]

To automate this process i need to build a script that downloads the file, convert it into xlsx and push it into google drive.

I have the last 2 steps covered, but i need to know if theres an api where i can download this CSV file from Azure.

I have not found anything online.

*UPDATE:
Another option that i have is getting the items of the query with a get request and then format them as xlsx.

I've been looking into the [azure devops queries api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) but this just list queries information but not the conten of them.

Any suggestion on how to the the workitems of a query?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to execute a REST call and have already defined query for your purpose, just have a look at this calls, this should do the trick:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{YourOrganization}/{YourProject}/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=6.0
```

in the response you will find a field called ID.

With this ID you can retrieve the query result by

```
HEAD https://dev.azure.com/{YourOrganization}/{YourProject}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=6.0
```

look here for docu

- [MS docu get query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)
- [MS docu get wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)